# How to submit form on one page to a different page using ajax call in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a page called `page2.php`. It has a form that allows you to search via jquery ajax call. The code is below. My question is, I have a different form on `page1.php`. How can I submit the form on `page1.php` to go to `page2.php` and have it execute the `page2.php` code below using the data from the form on `page1.php`? I know this is most likely simple, having a brain fart right now.

```
$(function() {
    $.validate({
        form: '#form_search',
        validateOnBlur: false,
        errorMessagePosition: 'top',
        onSuccess: function(form) {
            var formval = $(form).serialize();
            var formurl = '/page2.php?a=search';
            $('#form_results').html('<div class="form_wait_search">Searching, please wait...<br><img src="/images/search-loader.gif"></div>');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: formurl,
                data: formval,
                success: function(data){
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#form_errors').html(json.message);
                    $('#form_results').html(json.results);
                }
            });
            return false;   
        }   
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the forms Im referring to.

On `page1.php` this is like a module on the right side bar. Just a form that I want to post to `page2.php`

```
<div class="scontent_box1">
  <strong class="box_title"><i class="fa fa-search fa-flip-horizontal"></i> Find Locations</strong>
  <form method="post" action="/page2.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Street Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ad" placeholder="Enter Street Address...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>City, State or Zip Code</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ct" placeholder="Enter City, State or Zip Code...">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default blue_btn">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Now here is the form on `page2.php` that executes the ajax code above. I want `page1.php` to submit to `page2.php` and envoke the same jquery code above.

```
<div class="row no_gutters">
  <div class="search_page">
    <div id="form_errors"></div>
    <form method="post" id="form_search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ad">Street Address<span class="reqfld">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-validation="required" id="ad" name="ad" placeholder="Enter Street Address..." value="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ct">City, State or Zip Code<span class="reqfld">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-validation="required" id="ct" name="ct" placeholder="Enter City Name..." value="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default blue_btn btn-block">Search Locations</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="form_results"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it the validation that you want to be processed on each page the same? What is/are the important part(s) that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Where does form1 submits data to? Why don't you submit it to that page?

Comment: Basically I want page1.php form to submit and be treated the same as if the form on page2.php was being submitted. They both do the same thing. I just need to know how to get the form on page1.php to call the page2.php script using the data passed from the page1.php. All the form field names on page1.php are the exact same as the form on page2.php

Comment: Is it too much code to post the contents of both pages? I have a hard time putting my head around what you are doing without seeing the forms and the processing script of said forms? Just by your description, it sounds like what you are trying to do may be overly complex and just may need to be reworked.

Comment: Let me try explaining one more time because I think Im doing a poor job of it. On page1.php I have a form. I want this form to submit to page2.php. On page2.php I have the same form as page1.php. It uses the code in my OP to submit the form on page2.php to search. What I want is page1.php to submit to page2.php and envoke the same script above.

Comment: So you have the above script embedded in the one page, but not the other?

Comment: Correct. The page1.php form is like a module on the side menu. It allows people to quickly search. So I want that form to submit to page2.php and envoke that script in my original post.

Comment: Do the forms have the same id (`#form_search`)? If yes, why don't you just put the javascript in javascript file like `myscript.js` and then include that file in both page1.php and page2.php like this: `<script src="myscript.js"></script>`

Comment: Why can you not have this on a `scripts.js` file and include it in your header as a `<script src="scripts.js"></script>` so any and all pages can use it? EDIT: @Andrew said what I said...I was too late. :D

Comment: @Rasclatt great minds think alike :)

Comment: @John I personally think you may want to have a dispatch-type ajax page that all it does is listen for commands from any page that sends data it's way then acts accordingly based on a `switch` algorithm (or other automation scheme). Then you just have to include the `.js` file in the header and have all your ajax call one dispatch page which sends data back based on service or action.

Comment: Because I want the results to only show on page2.php. So when someone fills out the form on page1.php I want it to pass its form data to page2.php and envoke the search script in my OP. Both forms are the same, but I only want to show results on page2.php

Comment: I will still go back to my original request then which is, can you post more script (or truncated perhaps) of all pages involved in this transaction and indicate which pages are what? I know you know what you want, but without seeing it, I don't think it's possible (or at the least, extremely difficult) to give you a good solid answer based on your description(s) and sample jQuery.

Comment: Ok I added the form from page1.php and page2.php in my OP.

Comment: Where is the search script *(php presumably on page 2)*?

Comment: From what I can see, I still think you need to add a js page in header, add a `class="search_form"` (or similar) to each of the forms, then instead of invoking by id using `'#form_search'`, you would invoke using class: `.search_form`. Then you pass data to a centralized dispatcher php page.

Comment: Yes the search script is on page2.php. That is where the results need to show. If I didnt use ajax I would just submit the form on page1.php to page2.php via GET variables and process the data that way via php. But I decided to use AJAX because I dont want the page to reload when someone searches on page2.php. So now Im just trying to have page1.php envoke the search code on page2.php but instead of passing the data from the form on page2.php, I want to pass the data from the form on page1.php to the search code on page2.php

Comment: Also dont know how a dispatcher would work in this case. I use switch statements all the time via php as a dispatcher, however in this case all I want to do is have the form on page1.php submit to page2.php passing the form data to the page2.php search script so it can load the results on page2.php just like if they submitted the form on page2.php.

Comment: Yeah, I gotcha I think. So if I read you right, then you just want to access the php from both pages, one via page reload (submit), one via ajax request? Hopefully this is the right read, sorry if not! You are probably getting frustrated with the questions...

Comment: If what I said is true AND you are also wanting to access the validation javascript, then no, you can only access that js via a js source link or in the header using `<script>` tags.

Comment: @John Why don't you submit your form on page1 via POST without AJAX to page2? On page2 you could detect the request method, if it is POST, get the data and submit it via AJAX.

Comment: @postrel If the scenario is what I am assuming, this would be the route then just `exit;` if request is AJAX.

Comment: Hey guys, what I ended up doing was just processing the form normally if the form from page1.php was submitted. I think someone suggested that, I didnt want to do it but seemed like the only solution at this point. So if someone submitted the form from page1.php it would take them to page2.php and then via php handle the request and return results. Then if they wanted to search against while on page2.php, they simply fill out the form on page2.php and then ajax would take over. Thanks for the help guys, sorry I wasnt very good at explaining the issue.